# In which controls, other than Button, can WPF Geometry icons be shown without defining Stroke or Fill?

Tags: wpf, xaml, pathgeometry

I need to show icons like this:

```
<Geometry x:Key="Geometry.LeftArrow">M 6.5 0.5 L 7.5 1 L 7.5 0 L 6.5 0.5 z</Geometry>
```

If I put them in Button they're Ok. However I need to show them in many other places but they're not shown. Sometimes it helps to define Stroke/Fill but this is wrong. I don't want to make up some colors that are hardcoded and look stupid when Theme/Style is changed.

This works:

```
<Button>
    <Path Data="{StaticResource Geometry.LeftArrow}" Stretch="Uniform" MaxHeight="12"/>
</Button>
```

This does not:

```
<Label>
    <Path Data="{StaticResource Geometry.LeftArrow}" Stretch="Uniform" MaxHeight="12"/>
</Label>
```

So what is the logic here and how can I have just show them let's say next to some TextBox?

Comment: I tried this and the Path didn't get a default fill or stroke in a Button. My solution would be to define a default Path Style which sets Fill (or Stroke, whichever) to [`{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.controltextbrushkey(v=vs.110).aspx). A well-designed theme should use those SystemColors brush keys. If a theme isn't well designed, you can add some "shim" resource definitions which define SystemColors brush keys to appropriate theme resources.

Comment: Thanks! Ok. I thought this was some WPF thing. I have to find out from style&icon people why I don't need to set them for Button and can they create style as you suggested.

Comment: One way to make that happen would be having a default style for `Path` in the `Style.Resources` section of the default style for `Button`. If you've got style and icon people, I envy you, and yes, definitely talk to them about this.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly the case. Fill is bound to foreground of the ButtonBase ancestor. My question makes no sense. I really thought they are not shown at all, not that I can't see them cause they have no Fill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and the Path didn't get a default fill or stroke in a Button.

My solution would be to define a default `Path` Style which sets Fill (or Stroke, whichever) to [`{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.controltextbrushkey(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
<Style TargetType="Path">
    <Setter 
        Property="Fill" 
        Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" 
        />
</Style>
```

A well-designed theme should use those `SystemColors` brush keys. If a theme isn't well designed, you can add some "shim" resource definitions which define `SystemColors` brush keys to appropriate theme resources.

If I wanted to give `Path` a default fill in `Button` but not elsewhere, I could do that by defining that default `Path` style in the resources for the `Button` style:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Path">
            <Setter 
                Property="Fill" 
                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" 
                />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>

    <!-- other stuff -->
</Style>
```

And now that you've talked to your style and icon people (so jelly; we have to do that stuff for ourselves), it looks like that's the essence of what's happening here.